# Bootstrap datepicker not working in MVC project

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap, datepicker

I followed this guy's third solution:

https://blog.jigsawpieces.me/2014/07/23/lbd-adding-datetimepicker-control-to-mvc-project/

pretty much it said to install via Nuget Package Manager in Visual Studio:

```
Install-Package Bootstrap.v3.Datetimepicker
```

then to add this to Bundle.config:

```
bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/moment").Include(
                    "~/Scripts/moment.js"));
```

I see it display the calender icon next to the input field but when I click it the calendar does not drop down. Here is my Bundle.config file:

```
public static void RegisterBundles(BundleCollection bundles)
    {
        bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jquery").Include(
                    "~/Scripts/jquery-{version}.js",
                    "~/Scripts/jquery-ui*"));

        bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jqueryval").Include(
                    "~/Scripts/jquery.validate*"));

        // Use the development version of Modernizr to develop with and learn from. Then, when you're
        // ready for production, use the build tool at http://modernizr.com to pick only the tests you need.
        bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/modernizr").Include(
                    "~/Scripts/modernizr-*"));

        bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/moment").Include(
                   "~/Scripts/moment.js"));

        bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/bootstrap").Include(
                  "~/Scripts/bootstrap.js",
                  "~/Scripts/respond.js"));

        bundles.Add(new StyleBundle("~/Content/css").Include(
                  "~/Content/bootstrap.css", 
                  "~/Content/themes/base/jquery.ui.all.css",
                  "~/Content/site.css"));


    }
```

Here is my view which displays this input field:

```
<div class="row">
                            <div class='col-sm-6'>
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <div class='input-group date' id='datetimepicker1'>
                                        <input type='text' class="form-control datepicker" />
                                        <span class="input-group-addon">
                                            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span>
                                        </span>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <script type="text/javascript">
                                    $(function () {
                                        $('#datetimepicker1').datetimepicker({ format: 'dd MM yyyy - hh:ii' });
                                    });
                            </script>
                        </div>
```

What am I doing wrong? Why won't the calendar drop down and display the datepicker??

Here is my new Bundle.config. I added the other js and css files and still nothing:

```
public static void RegisterBundles(BundleCollection bundles)
    {
        bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jquery").Include(
                    "~/Scripts/jquery-{version}.js",
                    "~/Scripts/jquery-ui*"));

        bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jqueryval").Include(
                    "~/Scripts/jquery.validate*"));

        // Use the development version of Modernizr to develop with and learn from. Then, when you're
        // ready for production, use the build tool at http://modernizr.com to pick only the tests you need.
        bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/modernizr").Include(
                    "~/Scripts/modernizr-*"));

        bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/moment").Include(
                   "~/Scripts/moment.js"));

        bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/bootstrap").Include(
                  "~/Scripts/bootstrap.js",
                  "~/Scripts/bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.js",
                  "~/Scripts/respond.js"));

        bundles.Add(new StyleBundle("~/Content/css").Include(
                  "~/Content/bootstrap.css",
                  "~/Content/bootstrap-datetimepicker.min.css",
                  "~/Content/themes/base/jquery.ui.all.css",
                  "~/Content/site.css"));


    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are missing the datetimepicker resources.

From the blog you posted:

> Running this command added new versions of bootstrap-datetimepicker.js and bootstrap-datetimepicker.css to my project. The only additional configuration I needed to do was add moment.js to the BundleConfig.cs file

The previous steps added these files.

I created a new MVC project and got this working.

**BundleConfig.cs**

```
public static void RegisterBundles(BundleCollection bundles)
{
    bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jquery").Include(
                "~/Scripts/jquery-{version}.js"));

    bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jqueryval").Include(
                "~/Scripts/jquery.validate*"));

    bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/modernizr").Include(
                    "~/Scripts/modernizr-*"));

    bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/moment").Include(
                "~/Scripts/moment.js"));

    bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/bootstrap").Include(
              "~/Scripts/bootstrap.js",
              "~/Scripts/respond.js",
              "~/Scripts/bootstrap-datetimepicker.js"));

    bundles.Add(new StyleBundle("~/Content/css").Include(
             "~/Content/bootstrap.css",
             "~/Content/bootstrap-datetimepicker.css",
              "~/Content/site.css"));
}
```

**_Layout.cshtml**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>@ViewBag.Title - My ASP.NET Application</title>
    @Styles.Render("~/Content/css")
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/modernizr")
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container body-content">
        @RenderBody()
    </div>

    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/moment")
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/bootstrap")
    @RenderSection("scripts", required: false)
</body>
</html>
```

Note that Moment needs to be loaded before the datetimepicker. Moment was a separate download.

**Index.cshtml**

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4">
        <input type="text" id="datetimepicker1" />
    </div>
</div>

@section scripts {
    <script>
        $("#datetimepicker1").datetimepicker();
    </script>
}
```

Comment: so I should add bootstrap-datetimepicker.js and bootstrap-datetimepicker.css to my Bundle.config?

Comment: Here is my new bundle.config file. It still did not do anything different. :( I don't understand why. I attached my new bundle.config above in my question. @Jasen

Comment: Try removing jQuery-UI. Also, try removing all options from the `.datetimepicker()`. Inspect the page source to be sure the scripts and stylesheets are included. Check for script errors in the debug console.